# Rename using regex on maven-dependency-plugin:copy-dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I'd like to rename all dependencies to strip off SNAPSHOT so my file handling scripts and installer don't break when I release.

I presently, use maven-dependency-plugin:copy-dependencies and copy with individual artifacts listed and renamed.  I'd rather have something akin to ant's regex mapper establish a renaming rule.

Presently, I plan to copy-dependencies to 1st stage directory in prepare-package and use antrun's copy + regex mapper in package to copy/rename but that wastes time and space.

Is there a more direct way to approach this problem?  Can the dependency plugin handle rule based renames?

Thanks

Peter

Comment: Can you show the pom and describe in more detail what you like to do and what you like to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove the version from the dependencies, then add the stripVersion parameter to the plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <silent>true</silent>
                <outputDirectory>libs</outputDirectory>
                <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                <includeTypes>swc</includeTypes>
                <excludeGroupIds>com.adobe.flex.framework</excludeGroupIds>
                <excludeTypes>pom</excludeTypes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```